# Formatting Word document with Python

Tags: python

I've created a Word document using Python. Now I want to bold a part of text via Python, but I'm not sure how to do that: Can someone help?

Also, I've added a heading:

```
doc.add_heading(text='Analytics', level=0)
```

How to make this heading bold and underlined?

Comment: Can you provide your sample code. What libraries you are using. I can check and improve it.

Comment: I have a dataframe with two columns 

Name           Age
V                   27
X                   78

^ this is a sample, the real data has 49 such entries 

I've converted them to 

- My name is V : my age is 27
- My name is X : my name is 78

to get this I've written 

for item1, item 2 in df3.values

Answer (score 1):

In oder to change the style of a heading with python-docx, you have to [manipulate the style](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html) of the document. Here is an example of how to change the title to bold, underlined and red:

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor

document = Document()
styles = document.styles
styles['Heading 1'].font.bold = True
styles['Heading 1'].font.underline = True
styles['Heading 1'].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

p = document.add_heading('Analytics', 1)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

To manipulate a part of a text, you can partially add new sections with the add_run method of a paragraph, here's an example [from the documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.save('demo2.docx')
```

Combined, this should give you the following output:

[image]